# Build Basket Session from $_POST["sku"] & $_POST["qty"]

Tags: centos8, php-7.4

I'm really struggling here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a list of products on a page, each product has a form which posts two fields to a basket-controller.php

can somebody please show me how to create a session called basket-items with each post creating a separate sub array?  I want to be able to work with the arrays via the sku value to then add other info from the db etc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['add-to-basket-sku']]['name'] = $_POST['add-to-basket-name'];
$_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['add-to-basket-sku']]['price'] = $_POST['add-to-basket-price'];
$_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['add-to-basket-sku']]['qty'] = $_POST['add-to-basket-qty'];
```